# monotouch security issues

Tags: security, xamarin.ios

Are there any know security issues in monotouch? Any issues, vulnerabilities that I should be aware of.

Also, where can I find a best security practices guideline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing you are going to find is [Apple's security guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html)

MonoTouch adheres to Apples rules such as no dynamic code generation, app sandboxing, etc. I don't see how it would be less secure than an Objective-C app, since they can only expose the iOS APIs in C# what Apple exposes to Objective-C. MonoTouch of course has all the functionality in the .Net base class libraries, but I don't see how those would have security vulnerabilities since they are also locked down by Apple's rules.

I think in general, it's a good idea to:

- Don't store sensitive data in a plain text file
- Don't store sensitive data in NSUserDefaults unless encrypted
- If you use SQLite, look into a way to encrypt it like [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/)
- Use parameterized SQL for SQLite or use a library like [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and you don't have to worry about SQL injection

Comment: Hi @jonathanpeppers, what about mono for android and windows 8? Can u help with this? Thanks.

Comment: I would ask a new question -- an Android expert might pick it up. Although I think some of the same concepts apply.